# proof a theorem in linear algebra

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

prove that if λ1 and λ2 are two distinct eigenvalues of a matrix A and λ1 , λ2 are corresponding eigenvectors, respectively, then α1 and α2 are linearly independent

please help...

thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_1,u_2$ be eigenvectors corresponding to two distinct eigenvalues of $A:$ $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. Let $c_1u_1+c_2u_2$ be a linear combination of $u_1,u_2$. Now, $$c_1u_1+c_2u_2=0\implies A(c_1u_1+c_2u_2)=0\implies c_1\lambda_1 u_1+c_2\lambda_2u_2=0\\ \implies c_1u_1(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)=0\implies c_1=0$$ since $u_1\ne 0,\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$. Similarly, we can show that $c_2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two linearly dependent vectors, then one must be a multiple of the other. So without loss of generality, $\alpha_1 = k \alpha_2$. Applying $A$ on both sides gives us $\lambda_1 \alpha_1 = k \lambda_2 \alpha_2 = \lambda_1 \alpha_1$ which forces $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, a contradiction.